# How to filter Cassandra rows by two columns

Tags: filter, cassandra

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE detections.events (
    id UUID,
    event_type INT,
    created_time TIMESTAMP
    PRIMARY KEY ( id, event_type, created_time )
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( created_time DESC );
```

and 2 queries:

`SELECT * FROM detections.events WHERE id=?`

`SELECT * FROM detections.events WHERE event_type=?`

but, apparently, i'm unable to set up a table like that, if I do
`PRIMARY KEY ( id, created_time )` I can query by id, but, not by event_type

If I do `PRIMARY KEY ( event_type, created_time )`  I can query by event_type, but, not by id

There's a way that I can model my table to be able to accomplish both queries without creating a new table and still order by created_time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved that by using

`PRIMARY KEY ( id, created_time )`

`CREATE INDEX event_type_idx ON detections.events( event_type );`

more info: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useMultIndexes.html

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to create a materialized view out of your events table to support your cql. Secondary indexes are inefficient and require scanning the whole cluster.
For your case the materialized view definition would be like below:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW events_by_type AS
  SELECT 
     id, event_type, created_time FROM events 
  WHERE
     id IS NOT NULL AND 
     event_type IS NOT NULL AND 
     created_time IS NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY(event_type, created_time, id);
```

Now, you can query by `event_type` from `events_by_type` like any other table.